# How to get count of elements matching a predicate in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, predicate

Let's say we want to count the `NaN`'s in a javascript array.  We can use

```
let arr = [...Array(100)].map( (a,i) => i %10==0 ?  NaN : i )
console.log(arr)

> [NaN, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, NaN, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, NaN, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, NaN, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, NaN, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, NaN, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, NaN, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, NaN, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, NaN, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, NaN, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

let nans = arr.map( aa => isNaN(aa) ? 1 : 0).reduce((acc,a) => acc+a)
console.log(nans)
> 10
```

That does work.. but it is a bit challenging to remember the `reduce()` machinery every time. Is there a more concise construct by applying a predicate as so:

`arr.count( a => isNan(a))`

Comment: `arr.filter(isNaN).length`

Comment: ah right javascript has `filter`  . can you make that an answer?

Comment: An issue with `.filter` is that it requires creating an intermediate array which only goes on to be used for its `.length`, I think `.reduce` is a bit more appropriate

Comment: Ah interesting - _filter_ creates an intermediate array. But the `filter` is still OK for small arrays I guess

Comment: `filter` always creates a new array.  It's "intermediate" because it is only used to get a secondary, desired, result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out the elements that are not NaN.

```
arr.filter(isNaN).length
//or
arr.filter(function(it){ return isNaN(it); }).length
```

Comment: I like this one for small arrays and will keep in mind what @CertainPerformance has suggested for medium and larger ones where mem/performance matters

Answer (score 7):

You can have just a single `.reduce` where the accumulator is the number of NaNs found so far:

```js
const arr = [...Array(100)].map( (a,i) => i %10==0 ?  NaN : i );
const nans = arr.reduce((a, item) => a + isNaN(item), 0);
console.log(nans);
```

Comment: This is certainly an improvement (and upvoted). I'll wait for the `filter` answer that is spot -on for this use case.

Comment: Oh so the `filter` creates an intermediate array. Maybe that's OK for v small arrays but this approach is better for larger arrays where memory usage matters

Comment: This is an easily overlooked subtlety on considering the _size_ of the array. We have a "filter for small" and "reduce for big".

Answer (score 0):

Or `while` for even bigger...

```
const arr = [...Array(1e6)].map((a, i) => i % 10 == 0 ? NaN : i);

let
  i = arr.length,
  nans = 0;
  
while (i--) {
  nans += isNaN(arr[i]);
}

console.log(nans.toExponential());
```

---

```js
const arr = [...Array(100)].map((a, i) => i % 10 == 0 ? NaN : i);

const count = (arr, predicate) => {
  let c = 0, i = arr.length;
  while (i--) c += predicate(arr[i]);
  return c
};

const
  nans = count(arr, x => isNaN(x)),
  sevens = count(arr, x => x % 7 === 0);

console.log(`nans: ${nans}, sevens: ${sevens}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `forEach` loop instead of map and reduce

```js
const nanCount = (arr, count = 0) => (
  arr.forEach((num) => (count += isNaN(num))), count
);


const arr = [NaN, 0, 1, 3 , NaN];
console.log(nanCount(arr));
```